# undefined reference error when trying to implement abstract class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker

I have an abstract class that is meant to be an interface:

```
//hpp
#ifndef IMOVABLE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define IMOVABLE_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "StaticMovementPath.hpp"

class IMovable{
protected:
    StaticMovementPath *staticMovementPath;
public:
    IMovable();
    virtual setStaticMovementPath(StaticMovementPath *staticmovementPath) = 0;
};

#endif // IMOVABLE_HPP_INCLUDED

//cpp
#include "IMovable.hpp"

#include "StaticMovementPath.hpp"

IMovable::IMovable()
{
    staticMovementPath = new StaticMovementPath();
}



//hpp
#ifndef STATICMOVEMENTPATH_HPP_INCLUDED
#define STATICMOVEMENTPATH_HPP_INCLUDED

class StaticMovementPath{
public:
    StaticMovementPath();
};

#endif // STATICMOVEMENTPATH_HPP_INCLUDED

//cpp
#include "StaticMovementPath.hpp"

StaticMovementPath::StaticMovementPath(){
};




//hpp
#ifndef CAMERA_HPP
#define CAMERA_HPP

#include "IMovable.hpp"

class Camera: public IMovable{
public:
    Camera();
};

#endif // CAMERA_HPP

//cpp
#include "Camera.hpp"

#include "IMovable.cpp"

Camera::Camera() : IMovable(){
}
```

Compiling this will throw:

```
||=== Build: Debug in mapEditor (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\src\Camera.o||In function `ZN8IMovableC2Ev':|
...\src\IMovable.cpp|8|undefined reference to `StaticMovementPath::StaticMovementPath()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

If I don't define constructors (so the default ones are called), I get no error. However, I get the same error with constructors that have one or more parameters.

How do I make this work?

I know most of the code seems pointless, but I stripped it down as much as I could. The same error was thrown with the (more) complete code.

Comment: After overriding the default constructor in StaticMovementPath, are you sure `Camera.cpp` file is recompiled ?

Comment: I've rebuilt whole project, the error persists.

Comment: So, you removed the default constructor and provided constructor with parameters. Now if linker still complains about the default constructor then it's a hint that all source files are not recompiled. I would think it should fail at the compilation level rather than at linking level if at all default constructor is required.

Comment: I meant buliding. When I build the project I get the error.

Comment: Right, compiler or linker error after removing default constructor ?

Comment: I don't know. I press the cog in the CodeBlocks and I get the output I wrote below. I know I can compile the interface by itself, but if I implement it in a class, it fails when compiling/linking that class. I don't know if reference above to Camera.o was regarding failure to compile or faliure to link.

Comment: Damn cpp wasn't targeted for debug nor release. Stupidest bug ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StaticMovementPath.cpp wasn't targeted for debug nor release, so it wasn't compiling at all.